# LockForUpdate causes Deadlock if table is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Currently I am trying to upload some images parallel with [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/%20%22Dropzone%20Js).

This is part of the code, that handles the upload.

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
        $maxPos = GalleryImage::lockForUpdate()->max('pos');

    try {
        // some other code
        // .... 

        $galleryImage->pos = $maxPos + 1;
        $galleryImage->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \DB::rollBack();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return response('An error occured', 500);
    }
    \DB::commit();
```

If I do not use the lockForUpdate() I end up with duplicate positions in database.

The problem with above solution ist, that if the table is empty I get the error:

```
Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

But only for the second image I am uploading.

Additionally the autoincrement id skips the value 2  and goes like  1,3,4,5,6,7, ...

The Positions in the table are shown correctly 1,2,3,4....

I think the problem has to do with the table beeing empty initially, as I did not notice this problem, when there are already some entries in the table.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? Or Maybe using lockForUpdate() in combination with an aggregate function is wrong at all...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a different approach to transactions.

```
try {

    app('db')->transaction(function ()) {
        $maxPos = GalleryImage::lockForUpdate()->max('pos');
        // other code (...)
        $galleryImage->pos = $maxPos + 1;
        $galleryImage->save();
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // display an error to user
}
```

Should any exception occurs inside the callback, the transaction will rollback and free any locks.

Comment: Is there any difference to using  \DB::rollBack(); inside the catch block as I did ?